# How to access kibana from browser?

Tags: elasticsearch-opendistro

I installed elastic and Kibana as per the instructions mentioned here...

https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch/downloads.html#prod

I can connect to the local elastic server using curl:

```
#  curl -XGET https://localhost:9200 -u 'admin:admin' --insecure
{
xxx:xxx  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I checked the file /etc/kibana/kibana.yml to make sure that it is connecting to local elastic server.

```
elasticsearch.hosts: https://localhost:9200
```

I started the elastic service and confirm:

```
# ps aux | grep kibana
kibana    4740  109  1.3 848500 112308 ?       Rsl  06:49   0:02 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node /usr/share/kibana/bin/../src/cli/dist -c /etc/kibana/kibana.yml
```

But the kibana UI is not loading when I visit http://somedomain.com:5601

I am using ARM processor if that matters.

Comment: Do you add the same option as you curl command ? user/password and insecure in the kibana.yml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked after adding this one line to kibana config file.

```
vi /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

server.host: "0.0.0.0"
```